# Does rollBack improve performance?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, database-performance

I have just successfully attempted using beginTransaction() to execute my sql statements in my project using PHP. I have an array of items need to be written to the database, and each item must be validated against something before getting stored. One of the good things about turning off the auto-commit behaviour of a database is you can rollback the whole transaction if something goes wrong in the middle. In my project, if one item is invalid, the whole array should not be recorded in the database, which is why I chose to use this approach.

Now I am just wondering if this really is a better way in terms of performance? Because even if the last item in the array is validated, I still need to manually commit() the previous execution. Does commit repeat the sql execution?

The only advantage I can think of right now is you only need to do one loop instead of two if you want to validate them all (assuming all items are valid) and then write each of them.

Comment: SQL is _not_ a database product. It's just a language used by many RDBMS'. What database system are you using and what version?

Comment: Slightly OT: If the validity of the changes can be determined by looking at database state and the change itself, then it is arguably best to put the validation in a `BEFORE` trigger, so that the business logic is applied regardless of what client of application code is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit does not repeat SQL execution.

Typically, when working in a transactional, whenever you execute an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement, the database takes a copy of the records/data pages to a transaction log, and then executes the actual record changes.

If anybody else tries to access those records/data pages during the course of your transaction, they will be redirected to the copy in the transaction log.

Then, when you execute the commit, the data in the database itself is already updated, and all the server needs to do is delete the transaction log.

If you rollback rather than commit, then the database server backtracks through the transaction log, restoring all the records/data pages that you have updated to their original state, deleting each transaction log entry as it goes.

Therefore, a rollback is an overhead, because the database server has to restore the data to its pre-transaction state.

Comment: This description of rollback's implementation does not apply to PostgreSQL. With PG, the records before update are not copied anywhere, they stay in place. The system knows at any point in time if a row is current or not with its transaction IDs. The overhead is mostly that at some point in the future, VACUUM will have to run to reclaim the disk space used by these unused versions of the rows, but that is true for both commit and rollback.

Comment: So what Daniel said means rollbacks are impressively quick on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

First validate everything, then begin a transaction, database interaction. Transactions are not made to help validating the data.

Comment: Like I said, if I validate everything first, assuming everything is fine, I have to loop the array again to write each item to the db.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  Just because something *was* true at some time before the transaction began doesn't prove that it still *is* true when you go to apply the transaction, unless there is some synchronization outside the database itself.  A transaction is *exactly* the mechanism by which you can ensure database integrity in the face of concurrent modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use savepoints. From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html):

```
BEGIN;
     INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1);
     SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
       INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2);
     ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
     INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3); 
COMMIT;
```

You still have to validate your input, but you can now rollback within a single transaction. Using transactions can make the database faster because there are less (implicit) commits.

Comment: +1 - Unless you are going to far and your transaction takes very long and / or locks many tables in its course and starts to block more concurrent operations than necessary. Then you should split it into smaller transactions (in a smart way).

Comment: In the question it was explicitly stated that if any one item fails validation, none of them should be applied; so this suggestion is completely counter-productive.